# Service and BackgroundServiceExceptionBehavior

Tags: service

i have the next code and i try to implement the BackgroundServiceExceptionBehavior.Ignore

Becouse i having error and the service stop (I want to prevent it from stopping)

This is the error:
*System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)*

And this is the  CODE :

```
// Agregar Servicio
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    }).UseSerilog();
```

I would like to know how to implement the BackgroundServiceExceptionBehavior property

Thanks in advance !!